# Jackson ObjectMapper deserialization setVisibility of some attribute to None

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, deserialization

I am using model provided by external team to de-serialize JSON to Java object. However the JSON message has some field which failed to convert because it's not compatible:
Example: below is throwing:
`org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar from String value '17:00:00'`

Example JSON message:

```
"BirthDate": {
    "@type": "BirthDate",
    "startDate": "2015-01-19",
    "startTime": "17:00:00"}
```

I am using global CustomObjectWrapper
    public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

```
public CustomObjectMapper() {
    super();
    configure(Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    AnnotationIntrospector pair = new AnnotationIntrospector.Pair(new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(), new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector());
    setAnnotationIntrospector(pair);
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

appContext.xml(spring)

```
<bean id="jsonObjectMapper" class="com.org.CustomObjectMapper"/>
<bean id="birthDataFormat" class="org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat">
  <constructor-arg ref="jsonObjectMapper"/>
  <constructor-arg value="com.external.org.PersonModel"/>
</bean>
```

How can I tell the jackson to not convert the `startDate` and `startTime` ?
The model is not something that I control and I could not write all the models again. What would be the alternate?

Comment: You'll probably need a custom deserializer to transform the two JSON date and time fields into a single Java field. Also, please specify the Jackson version. This looks like you're using the outdated Jackson 1, but it's not clear.

Comment: Hi Chrylis, I want to ignore some fields from the JSON message and let de-serializer not try to convert them to Java object. There are some annotation available but since I am importing model from external, I cannot do that and writing all the custom POJO is one option, but that would be too much of work

Comment: @AnujAcharya can you share your java object?